# How can this rare '<a>' tag markup be written in pug?

Tags: html, vue.js, web, nuxt.js, pug

**More features and functionalities (see all [here](https://google.com))**

I am trying to write out the above in pug. I have tried to write it how I'd write it in html, but it just won't render correctly.

Below is how I tried to write it:

```
li More features and functionalities (see all nuxt-link(to="/page") here )
```

How would you write this?

Comment: Using a pipe for example. See https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html

Comment: The link posted in bold sends you to Google. Please share the Pug code you are trying to convert to HTML. In the meantime, I came across this HTML converter that may be useful - https://pughtml.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Nuxt, but I'm assuming the final markup you're going for is this:

```
<li>More features and functionalities (see all <nuxt-link to="/page">here</nuxt-link>)</li>
```

There are many ways to write this in Pug, but one of the cleanest is using [tag interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#tag-interpolation):

```
li More features and functionalities (see all #[nuxt-link(to="/page") here])
```

But also note that [it's bad practice to make the text "here" or "click here" a link](https://webaim.org/techniques/hypertext/#link_to_link). The text of links should make sense outside of their context.